# Randomize order of divs in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have looked around at the numerous questions regarding randomizing divs and have tweaked some code that does the job almost perfectly.

I have a form that contains 10 multichoice questions, on the page load I am wanting to randomize the order that they appear in; but using the code below they end up in a random order, with the submit button of the form above them.

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/application/multichoice" accept-charset="UTF-8">    

    <div class="form-group">
        <h3>Multiple Choice</h3>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi1">1) What is our server&#039;s genre?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi1" type="radio" value="a" id="multi1"> Light Roleplay</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi1" type="radio" value="b" id="multi1"> Deathmatch/Freeroam</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi1" type="radio" value="c" id="multi1"> Heavy Roleplay</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi1" type="radio" value="d" id="multi1"> Drifting</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi2">2) An advanced knowledge of which of the following languages is required on our server?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi2" type="radio" value="a" id="multi2"> Russian</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi2" type="radio" value="b" id="multi2"> English</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi2" type="radio" value="c" id="multi2"> Latvian</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi2" type="radio" value="d" id="multi2"> All languages are acceptable</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi3">3) Which of the following activities are controlled because of Rule 6?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi3" type="radio" value="a" id="multi3"> Torturing a character</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi3" type="radio" value="b" id="multi3"> Character killing another player's character</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi3" type="radio" value="c" id="multi3"> Disregarding another player's out-of-character communication</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi3" type="radio" value="d" id="multi3"> Ignoring an administrator's ruling</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi4">4) If you wish to steal a property from another player, which of the following is the correct way to do so?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi4" type="radio" value="a" id="multi4"> Obtain administrator permission beforehand by using the report system in-game</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi4" type="radio" value="b" id="multi4"> Roleplay it first, then ask for an administrator to transfer the property</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi4" type="radio" value="c" id="multi4"> Have the stolen property transferred by filling out the application</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi4" type="radio" value="d" id="multi4"> None of the above</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi5">5) Which of the following activities is against the rules?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi5" type="radio" value="a" id="multi5"> Killing several gang members in a drive-by without having interacted with them at all beforehand</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi5" type="radio" value="b" id="multi5"> Requiring that anyone who joins your organization agrees to a CK contract</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi5" type="radio" value="c" id="multi5"> Demanding a reason for being killed from your killer through out-of-character communication</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi5" type="radio" value="d" id="multi5"> Robbing someone's character near the boardwalk</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi6">6) Which of the following player names would be acceptable?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi6" type="radio" value="a" id="multi6"> Wei Jiang</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi6" type="radio" value="b" id="multi6"> Asuka Kasen</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi6" type="radio" value="c" id="multi6"> Cristiano Ronaldo</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi6" type="radio" value="d" id="multi6"> Raimonds Vejonis</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi7">7) When is it acceptable to completely ignore another player&#039;s out-of-character communication?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi7" type="radio" value="a" id="multi7"> Always</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi7" type="radio" value="b" id="multi7"> If they are breaking server rules or encouraging the breaking of server rules</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi7" type="radio" value="c" id="multi7"> Anytime, as long as it isn't to tell a player why you killed them</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi7" type="radio" value="d" id="multi7"> Never</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi8">8) You are killed. You see your killer later, yell out to them your reasoning for killing them, and kill them to take revenge. Is that acceptable?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi8" type="radio" value="a" id="multi8"> No, because you did not roleplay with them sufficiently beforehand, so you are guilty of deathmatching</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi8" type="radio" value="b" id="multi8"> Yes, because you had a solid reason for killing them</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi8" type="radio" value="c" id="multi8"> No, because killing another player just for killing you is not allowed</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi8" type="radio" value="d" id="multi8"> Yes, as long as you interacted with them before killing them</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi9">9) Which of the following could be classified as powergaming?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi9" type="radio" value="a" id="multi9"> Killing another player as part of a contract killing</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi9" type="radio" value="b" id="multi9"> Roleplaying acting on instructions from an NPC of your own creation</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi9" type="radio" value="c" id="multi9"> Helping a friend evade police who asked for your help over an out-of-character form of communication</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi9" type="radio" value="d" id="multi9"> Committing a crime in an unrealistic area</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group question'>
        <label for="multi10">10) Which of the following could be classified as metagaming?</label>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi10" type="radio" value="a" id="multi10"> Assuming a character's gang affiliations by their clothing</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi10" type="radio" value="b" id="multi10"> Identifying an organization in-game based on publicly available information in an in-character section of the forums</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi10" type="radio" value="c" id="multi10"> Sharing potentially sensitive in-character information about an organization out of character</label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input name="multi10" type="radio" value="d" id="multi10"> Accepting money in-game to kill a target</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

    </form>
```

**jQuery that I am using to randomize them**

```
$.fn.randomize = function(selector){
    (selector ? this.find(selector) : this).parent().each(function(){
        $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
            return Math.random() - 0.5;
        }).detach().appendTo(this);
    });

    return this;
};

$('form').randomize('.question');
$('.question').randomize('.radio');
```

As per the screenshot below, you can see what I mean regarding the submit button:

[image: Submit button above the questions]

How can I get the questions randomized like I have done, without the submit button moving up to the top too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detach the submit button too, and reattach it after your randomizing function.

Or wrap the MC divs within another div, then perform the randomizing.

Comment: I would recommend the second solution, put all question in one wrapper div before sorting. This seems to be a better way to do it.

Comment: The first way would preserve the nesting structure, while the second way would alter it. In some cases you might want to preserve the structure, e.g. you have tightly bounded css declaration. The OP question does not seem to matter though. I would have performed the second solution myself as well.

Comment: The second solution worked a treat! I'm not super experienced with jQuery and this solution completely alluded me.